# How To Test AccountController In ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, testing

I Want To Test Account Controller In Asp.net 
**Account Controller Is Part Of Identity**
Is it Necessary To Testing Account Controller?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work at Typemock.

It's possible and also quite easy to test ASP.net Controllers in general and Account Controller in particular when using [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com).
Here is an example to a test for the Login method of Account controller:

The method under test(taken from VS2015 MVC template):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestMethod, Isolated]
public async Task TestWhenLoginIsBad_ErrorMessageIsShown()
{
    // Arrange
    // Create the wanted controller for testing 
    var controller = new AccountController(); 
    var loginData = new LoginViewModel { Email = "support@typemock.com", Password = "password", RememberMe = false };

    // Fake the ModelState
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => controller.ModelState.IsValid).WillReturn(true);

    // Ignore AddModelError (should be called when login fails)
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", "")).IgnoreCall();

    // Fake HttpContext to return a fake ApplicationSignInManager
    var fakeASIM = Isolate.WhenCalled(() => controller.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>()).ReturnRecursiveFake();

    // When password checked it will fail. Note we are faking an async method
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeASIM.PasswordSignInAsync(null, null, true, true)).WillReturn(Task.FromResult(SignInStatus.Failure));

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Login(loginData, "http://www.typemock.com/");

    // Assert
    // The result contains login data, doesn’t redirect
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
    Assert.AreSame(loginData, (result as ViewResult).Model);
    // Make sure that the code added an error
    Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithExactArguments(() => controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt."));
}
```

If you would like to learn more [here](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmockingaspdotnetmvc.htm) is the full example.

Comment: Thanks Daniel
How To Installing Isolate?
Is Isolate Nuget Package?

Comment: There is a link to the Typemock Isolator site in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For unit testing in general, you can take a look this article

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs

For testing on Account Controller, please take a look the following article

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2014/08/21/mvc-series-part-2-accountcontroller-testing/

```
   [Test]
   public void ShouldNotAcceptInvalidUser()
  {
  // Arrange
  Mock<IMembershipService> membership = new Mock<IMembershipService>();
  membership.Setup(m => m.ValidateUser(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
          .Returns(false);
  Mock<IFormsService> forms = new Mock<IFormsService>();
var logonModel = new LogOnModel() { UserName = "", Password = "" };
var controller = new AccountController(membership.Object, forms.Object);

// Act
var result = controller.LogOn(logonModel, "") as ViewResult;

// Assert
Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo("Index"));
Assert.False(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
Assert.That(controller.ModelState[""], 
            Is.EqualTo("The user name or password provided is incorrect."));}
```

Comment: I Want Testing Login MEthod's OF Account Controller 
Can You Help Me?